# Deleting rows and columns in matrix based on values in diagonal in R

Tags: r, matrix

With R: If I have a square matrix, what would be the easiest(as well as fast) way to delete the row and column if the value on the diagonal is less than five? For example

```
       x1  x2  x3  x4
    x1 13  15  12  25
    x2 23  4   23  34
    x3 21  11  1   11
    x4 11  22  23  33
```

The code would delete row 2 and column 2, and row 3 and column 3. I tried doing for(i in 1:nrow(Mx)), but deleting rows changes the total number of rows.

The final matrix would look like

```
       x1  x4
    x1 13  25
    x4 11  33
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `diag` function and logical comparison with `<` and the `[` subset operator like this...

```
idx <- ! diag(m) < 5
m <- m[ idx , idx ]
```

e.g.

```
m
#   x1 x2 x3 x4
#x1 13 15 12 25
#x2 23  4 23 34
#x3 21 11  1 11
#x4 11 22 23 33

idx <- ! diag(m) < 5    
m <- m[ idx , idx ]

m
#   x1 x4
#x1 13 25
#x4 11 33
```

Comment: 17 secs faster than me. But she also wants to select cols.

Comment: @Roland whoops. Updated. (although I probably shouldn't do the comparison twice!

Comment: Is there a way to have the row name print out when it's deleted?

Comment: @Judy Well before you do the deleting you can do `which( diag(m) < 5 )`

Comment: @Judy  Not directly. But once you have `idx` , `rowNames(m)[which(!idx)]`   should return the names of removed rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not the more elegant or fastest solution, but it works

```
mat <- matrix(c(13, 23, 21, 11, 15, 4, 11, 22, 12, 23,
                1, 23, 25, 34, 11, 33), nrow = 4)

ind <- which(diag(diag(mat)) > 5, arr.ind = TRUE)

mat[ind[,1], ind[,2]]
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]   13   25
## [2,]   11   33
```